# asssertion failure debugging wont fix

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, assertion

i get an assertion failure while trying to debug my file or running it's exe. the debug output tells me there is an

> Exception at 0x00f0155f in ok.exe: Access violation while reading at position 0x0000000

the line marked in the cpp file is as follows:

```
assert(SUCCEEDED(pUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_ICUIPower, (void**)&pCUIPower)));
```

what should i try?

Comment: It would appear that `pUnknown` is `NULL`. Figure out why.

Comment: Right, i set an variable to high in which case, it's defined as null. Thank you!